# How can I reload a page and breakpoint Branch with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to reload only once when the window size changes.

When the window size is changed, you want to execute reload only once.

The reason is that pc uses tabs and smartphones turn into an accordion.

```
if (window.matchMedia('screen and (max-width:767px)').matches) {

location.reload();
} else if (window.matchMedia('screen and (min-width:768px)').matches) {

location.reload();

} else {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout):

```
var resizeListener;

//the amount of time to wait after the resizing has finished before calling our function
var pause = 500;

$(window).resize(function(){

  //every time the window resize is called cancel the setTimeout() function
  clearTimeout(resizeListener);

  //set out function to run after a specified amount of time 
  resizeListener = setTimeout(function(){
    alert("The user has done resizing the window");
  },pause);

});
```

Source: https://thepixel.ninja/jquery/how-to-run-a-function-after-window-resize-using-jquery/